# Datastore statistics not updated for a week

Tags: google-app-engine, statistics, google-cloud-datastore, admin, dashboard

Datastore statistics is not updated for about a week.

I’m not sure it is wrong, but it’s a bit confusing.

Is there any way to update statistics more regularly or I just need to wait?

Or may be it is some kind of bug?

Here is screenshot of Datastore Statisctics page (292 MB displayed):

[image]

While Dashboard shows about 36 GB of data already in store:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a current issue with the engine.
Here's the discussion.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/pktY3a3Kzu4

So I guess you're just going to have to wait until it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a defect report about [Datastore Statistics not updating](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10613) at least once every 24 hours (issue 10613).  Please star it and/or chime in with comments.